Media3 (ExoPlayer) handle multile Tracks with the same name
TDLR; An Android app that plays DASH streaming video. The manifest file (.mpd) have multiple languages and some of them have multiple versions of the same language. For example:
fr 
fr 
en
du

Here I have two versions of English, Deutsch and two French versions. How do I handle the french case. This is how I retrieve the audio track info:
    fun getAudioInfo(): Map<String, Any> {
        val audioLanguages: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        var selectedAudio: String = AUTO

        for (trackGroup in EPlayer.p?.currentTracks!!.groups) {
            for (i in 0 until trackGroup.length) {
                // Current Individual track information.
                val trackType = trackGroup.type
                val isSupported = trackGroup.isTrackSupported(i)
                val isSelected = trackGroup.isTrackSelected(i)
                val trackFormat = trackGroup.getTrackFormat(i)
                val trackLanguage = trackFormat.language


                // Add the retrieved AudioLanguage
                if (trackLanguage != null && isSupported && trackType == 1) {
                    audioLanguages.add(trackLanguage)

                    if (isSelected) {
                        selectedAudio = trackLanguage
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        val info = mapOf(
            "audioTracks" to audioLanguages,
            "selectedAudioTrack" to selectedAudio
        )

        Log.d(TAG, "*** audioInfo to be returned: $info")

        return info
    }

And this is how I select an audio track:
fun changeAudioTrack(preferredAudio: String) {
        Log.d(TAG, "*** changeAudioTrack, $preferredAudio")

        val trackSelector = EPlayer.p?.trackSelector as? DefaultTrackSelector
        trackSelector?.parameters = trackSelector!!.parameters.buildUpon()
            .setPreferredAudioLanguage(preferredAudio)
            .build()

        logTracks()
    }

The preferredAudio variable will contain (fr, en, du) etc, so it's not really accurate in when having multiple version of the same language.
How do I fix this?
